# Search for XML node by string over different XML Objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I looking for a way to search and remove node by a name.

I have XML for example and I want to remove node `<aRemove>`

I tried using :

```
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//aRemove");
xmlDoc.SelectNodes(".//aRemove");
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("a aRemove");
```

The `XML` file :

```
 <a>

        <a1>
           <a12>
                  <aRemove> </aRemove>
           </a12>

        </a1>

        <a2>

        <a2>

   </a>
```

It never find that node. My XML's are different...one have `<aRemove>` in `<a1></a1>` and other inside `<b><b3></b3></b>`.

**EDIT:** some of the nodes in some XML's have attributes, for example :

```
<a2=t655> </a2>
```

How can I search for a node by string and remove it it different XML's for every one?

Comment: Are you sure your XML does not contain `xmlns` attributes?

Comment: some document have attributes...is it matter?

Comment: wow, is that a valid xml format, `<a2=t655>`? not `<a2 attributeName=t655>`? Sorry if that is actually valid, I just have never seen xml in that format before..

Comment: Yes, namespaces do matter for XML. Next time please try to provide small, but valid sample of data you have problem with... Side note: make sure to accept answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be easy with System.Xml.Linq.

```
 var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);//alternatively, you can load xml from file with XElement.Load(filepath)
 xml.XPathSelectElements(".//aRemove").Remove();
```

**Edit:**

As Alexei Levenkov suggested in comment, if `aRemove` elements have namespaces associated with them, and you want to remove all elements with name `aRemove`, irrespective of to which namespace they belong, you may try with the xpath `".//*[local-name()='aRemove']`. The code snippet with xml linq will be,

```
 var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);//alternatively, you can load xml from file with XElement.Load(filepath)
 xml.XPathSelectElements(".//*[local-name()='aRemove']").Remove();
```

Comment: +0: OP already claims that `".//aRemove"` XPath does not find nodes - so most likely there is some other problem (like namespaces).

Comment: `local-name()` is a C# attribute or I should change it to any string?

Comment: local-name() is an xpath function, it gives you the name of an element, ignoring its namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
        string fileName = @"c:\test\test.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        doc.Descendants("aRemove").Remove<XElement>();
        doc.Save(fileName);
```